# Building a lamp with a docking station to power my phone.

Tags: junction-box, lamp

I want to make a lamp with a docking station that can power and charge my phone, can I use a junction box to combined both cables so only one cable goes to the plug?

Comment: Why do you need a junction box?  Can't you simply contain the wiring within the lamp housing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a hobby project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the image that I came up with based on your question. Yes, it's a free country, and you may do this, but you will not be able to sell this device on a commercial level without having it UL listed (wal-mart won't buy it).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'm not looking to sell, I'm in the UK so I don't have a wal-mart. I simply didn't want two cables coming from the lamp/docking station so was hoping there was an easy way to connect the cables and run them through one plug. I've clearly shown my lack of knowledge in electrical products so I might just accept having two plugs. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: @ChrisKay I think that you should draw a diagram. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you need to move the lamp around, you may find it easier to get an outlet purpose made for this.  You could google "Leviton T5632-W" for example.  You can procure such a device through Amazon and other retailers.  And they are already UL approved.
[image]

Comment: Nice! I've been looking for that for a long time. Still looking for a 12V receptacle, too.